# running UI tests remotely on a VM in Azure pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, psexec, ui-testing, sysinternals

I have to automate running UI tests remotely on a VM in Azure pipeline. I can't use build agent for it.
I am using vsconsole.exe to execute the test cases. Now when i run it, through sysinternals psexec, it fails because it need "Active Desktop".(Unable to load DLL 'rasapi32.dll': A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed.)
Is something that i can do for automating that?

Comment: Are you using a script in the pipeline to run the application on the VM through psexec ? 
If yes, you could try to directly run the same script on the VM.
This  [ticket](https://superuser.com/questions/302770/psexec-issue-when-running-an-application-on-a-windows-server-2008-r2-machine-fro) may be useful. You could share the pipeline definition and  the debug log (set the variable: system.debug = true and run it) .

Comment: yes, i use a script in the pipeline to run the application on the VM through psexec. If i run this script directly on the VM, it's works fine.

Comment: if i use windows scheduler to run this script then run schedule task with psexec, it's solve this error, but i get an error due UI tests cannot run in non interactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

> An error due UI tests cannot run in non interactive mode.

You need to determine the Agent type (`Microsoft-hosted` or `Self-hosted`) you are using.

For Microsoft hosted agents:

You could try to use the [“vs2017-win2016”](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2016-Readme.md) Microsoft-hosted agent.

According to [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#visible-ui-testing-using-microsoft-hosted-agents) ：

> Microsoft-hosted agents are pre-configured for UI testing and UI tests for both web apps and desktop apps.

If the Microsoft-hosted agents couldn’t meet your requirements, I recommend that you could [create a self-hosted agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-windows?view=azure-devops#choose-interactive-or-service-mode).

You need to set the Agent as **interactive mode** and **auto-logon** enabled.

Note: Setting auto-logon mode requires running **config.cmd** file as an **administrator** role.

Here is a doc about [running UI test](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/test/ui-testing-considerations?view=azure-devops&tabs=mstest#ui-testing-in-visible-ui-mode), you could refer to it.